# Checking for exception in XML

Tags: xml, qt, qdomdocument

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport>
    <ServiceException>abc</ServiceException>
    <ServiceException>def</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

And i've created code like this:

```
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(data); // data is QByteArray that contains XML    
QDomNodeList report = doc.elementsByTagName("ServiceExceptionReport");
QDomNodeList exceptions = doc.elementsByTagName("ServiceException");

if (report.isEmpty()){
    ui->textEdit->insertHtml("<font color=\"green\">No exceptions found</font><br>");

} else {
    ui->textEdit->insertHtml("<font color=\"orange\">Found ServiceExceptionReport. Reading ServiceExceptions...</font><br>");
    qDebug() << exceptions.size(); //Program shows 2 here
    for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.size(); i++) {
        QDomNode n = report.item(i);
        QDomElement exception = n.firstChildElement("ServiceException");
        QString number =  QString::number(i);
        QString exceptiontxt = exception.text();
        ui->textEdit->insertHtml("<font color=\"red\">Error no. " + number + "&#58;" + exceptiontxt + "</font><br>"); 
    }
}
```

Program writes this in the textEdit:

```
Found ServiceExceptionReport. Reading ServiceExceptions...
Error no. 1 abc
Error no. 2          <-- This is my problem. There should be 'def'
```

Why `def` not showing in `textEdit`? How can i fix that?

btw. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mismatched how you get QDomElement for `ServiceException` xml node.

Following lines of you code:

```
QDomNode n = report.item(i);
QDomElement exception = n.firstChildElement("ServiceException");
```

Should be replaced with something like this:

```
QDomNode n = exceptions.item(i);
QDomElement exception = n.toElement();
```

In your code, you are trying to iterate over `QDomNodeList exceptions` list, but in the loop you call `report.item(i)` instead of `exceptions.item(i);`